# How to change the bootclasspath?

Tags: java, bazel

In a project I use Bazel 0.11.1 running Oracle Java 8 to produce Java 7 compatible .class files. While there are other ways to achieve this, I simply added the necessary source/target options with `--javacopt` to my `.bazelrc`.

This works fine, but it is good practice to change the bootclasspath as well, in order to avoid unwanted dependencies to creep in. But how do I achieve this with Bazel?

Adding `-bootclasspath` to `--javacopt` does not seem to take effect. So it seems I would have to resort to a custom java_toolchain, but I'm having trouble to get it running at all!

```
java_toolchain(
    name = "__jdk7",
    bootclasspath = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:bootclasspath"],
    encoding = "UTF-8",
    extclasspath = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:extclasspath"],
    genclass = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:genclass"],
    header_compiler = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:turbine"],
    ijar = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:ijar"],
    javabuilder = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:javabuilder"],
    javac = ["@bazel_tools//third_party/java/jdk/langtools:javac_jar"],
    javac_supports_workers = True,
    jvm_opts = [
        "-XX:+TieredCompilation",
        "-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1",
    ],
    singlejar = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:singlejar"],
    source_version = "8",
    target_version = "8",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

yields

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ANNOTATION_PROCESSOR_MODULE_PATH
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations.initHandlers(Locations.java:1976)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations.<init>(Locations.java:145)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.BaseFileManager.createLocations(BaseFileManager.java:115)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.BaseFileManager.<init>(BaseFileManager.java:76)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.<init>(JavacFileManager.java:147)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.lambda$preRegister$0(JavacFileManager.java:139)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context.get(Context.java:150)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context.get(Context.java:187)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.<init>(Enter.java:140)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.instance(Enter.java:112)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr.<init>(DeferredAttr.java:109)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr.instance(DeferredAttr.java:99)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.<init>(Resolve.java:123)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.instance(Resolve.java:159)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.<init>(Check.java:116)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.instance(Check.java:104)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Modules.<init>(Modules.java:184)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Modules.instance(Modules.java:174)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symtab.<init>(Symtab.java:481)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symtab.instance(Symtab.java:88)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.<init>(Attr.java:128)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.instance(Attr.java:119)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.<init>(Annotate.java:105)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.instance(Annotate.java:80)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:252)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.instance(ClassReader.java:245)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.<init>(ClassFinder.java:183)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.instance(ClassFinder.java:176)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.<init>(JavaCompiler.java:379)
    at com.google.devtools.build.buildjar.javac.BlazeJavaCompiler.<init>(BlazeJavaCompiler.java:41)
    at com.google.devtools.build.buildjar.javac.BlazeJavaCompiler.<init>(BlazeJavaCompiler.java:32)
    at com.google.devtools.build.buildjar.javac.BlazeJavaCompiler$1.make(BlazeJavaCompiler.java:76)
    at com.google.devtools.build.buildjar.javac.BlazeJavaCompiler$1.make(BlazeJavaCompiler.java:67)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context.get(Context.java:150)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.instance(JavaCompiler.java:110)
    at com.google.devtools.build.buildjar.javac.BlazeJavacMain.compile(BlazeJavacMain.java:117)
    at com.google.devtools.build.buildjar.SimpleJavaLibraryBuilder$2.invokeJavac(SimpleJavaLibraryBuilder.java:121)
    at com.google.devtools.build.buildjar.ReducedClasspathJavaLibraryBuilder.compileSources(ReducedClasspathJavaLibraryBuilder.java:54)
    at com.google.devtools.build.buildjar.SimpleJavaLibraryBuilder.compileJavaLibrary(SimpleJavaLibraryBuilder.java:124)
    at com.google.devtools.build.buildjar.SimpleJavaLibraryBuilder.run(SimpleJavaLibraryBuilder.java:132)
    at com.google.devtools.build.buildjar.BazelJavaBuilder.processRequest(BazelJavaBuilder.java:105)
    at com.google.devtools.build.buildjar.BazelJavaBuilder.runPersistentWorker(BazelJavaBuilder.java:67)
    at com.google.devtools.build.buildjar.BazelJavaBuilder.main(BazelJavaBuilder.java:45)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `default_java_toolchain`:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:default_java_toolchain.bzl", "default_java_toolchain")

default_java_toolchain(
  name = "__jdk7",
  jvm_opts = [
      "-Xbootclasspath/p:$(location @bazel_tools//third_party/java/jdk/langtools:javac_jar)",
      "-XX:+TieredCompilation",
      "-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1",
  ],
  javac = ["@bazel_tools//third_party/java/jdk/langtools:javac_jar",],
  bootclasspath = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:platformclasspath.jar",],
  visibility = ["//visibility:public",],
  source_version = "7",
  target_version = "7",
)
```

In your `.bazelrc` file add a reference to the toolchain, e.g.,

```
build --java_toolchain=//:__jdk7
test --java_toolchain=//:__jdk7
```

Comment: Thanks very much! That did it! I'd already try `default_java_toolchain`, but did not include the `-Xbootclasspath` flag.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working solution:

```
default_java_toolchain(
  name = "jdk7",
  jvm_opts = [
      "-Xbootclasspath/p:$(location @bazel_tools//third_party/java/jdk/langtools:javac_jar)",
      "-XX:+TieredCompilation",
      "-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1",
  ],
  javac = ["@bazel_tools//third_party/java/jdk/langtools:javac_jar"],
  bootclasspath = ["jdk7.jar"],
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
  source_version = "7",
  target_version = "7",
)
```

`jdk7.jar` has been manually created with the help of `DumpPlatformClassPath.java` provided below `bazel_tools/tools/jdk`.